# How to efficiently Produce Correct If/Else or CASE from Logic Grid Layout

Tags: sql, if-statement, conditional-statements, case

How can I use the grid to come up with efficient concise code?  If I don't use the grid are there better ways to approach conditional logic and am I using the correct terminology to describe my question?

When I'm presented with producing conditional logic output based on the values returned by multiple variables I often dive right in and begin coding however this is not the proper way to do it as far as I understand.  When presented with complex logic paths how are the more experienced formerly trained people coming up with the concise and efficient conditional logic?

For example I have the below possible Status outcomes based on the values in the variables A, B, C, D.  In my case this is a very simplified example of the request I am currently implementing.  The status values are simply based on the request.  For example to put the first row into words where all values = 1 it could read something like this "When the conditions A, B and C are TRUE... set the Status to 'T' if condition D is met otherwise set to 'A'".

Reading conditional logic in plain English can be painful and so I've compiled a grid laying out the possible conditions that produce the requested "Status".

[image]

How can I use the grid to come up with efficient concise code?

**Below is my mock attempt but this is my simply diving right in which doesn't get me the most efficient route**

```
WITH conditions AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS A, 1 AS B, 1 AS C, 1 AS D, 'T' AS desiredStatus UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 1, 1, 0, 'A' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 1, 0, 0, 'A' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 0, 1, 1, 'H' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 0, 1, 0, 'H' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 0, 0, 0, 'A' UNION ALL
    SELECT 0, 1, 1, 1, 'H' UNION ALL
    SELECT 0, 1, 1, 0, 'H' UNION ALL
    SELECT 0, 0, 1, 1, 'H' UNION ALL
    SELECT 0, 0, 1, 0, 'H'
)
SELECT A, B, C, D, desiredStatus, 
   CASE WHEN A > 0 AND B > 0 THEN CASE WHEN C > 0 AND D > 0 THEN 'T' ELSE 'A' END 
        WHEN A > 0 AND B = 0 THEN 'H'
   END AS codedStatus
FROM conditions
```

Comment: So my first thought is to sort the data by each column as seen in the screenshot.  But I also thought that perhaps I should sort the data by the desired Status and work the logic individually for each Status.  I just don't know if either method is better or worse or if there are better approaches I have yet to be exposed to.

Comment: I realize this doesn't answer your question, but my first thought seeing this is: If your logic is provided in that table format, why not use it as a real mapping table instead of converting it to CASE statements?

Comment: As strategies I would say you can: 1) reduce the logic by using a tree of logic conditions, or 2) Store all combinations and the expected outcome in a table and then perform lookup on it when a case comes in. The benefit of option #2 is that if the rules change later, you don't need to deploy a new version of the code to production, but a simple SQL UPDATE will do the trick; in other words, the logic is extracted from the code.

Comment: @EdmCoff I thought about that... I created the table based on the request but some of the values can be neatly sectioned but not sure if that makes it more concise... for example I could wrap Conditions A and B together in the first CASE and then work out each C and D values OR I can code four individual CASE Statements that work with each outcome individually.  How do I know what is better or if any is better or even if it matters?

Comment: As an additional thought, I would say: don't over think it. Plan for the future, but not too much. Save the effort of building an ivory tower. Cheap, direct solutions are often be the better ones, in terms of cost and opportunity.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the concern. If you maintain the table, there shouldn't be any need for case statements. You just join with 4 equals statements every time you want a value. You can use a function if writing out the join each time doesn't make sense.

Comment: Also, in terms of `efficient`, scalar calulations like these rarely take even a noticable amount of the execution time.  Reads from disk, index scans, range lookups, hsh joins, etc, they take effort, this does not.  It would be hard to do this badly even if you wanted to.

Comment: You might find Karnaugh maps to be enlightening.

Comment: @shawnt00 Yes!  That is the mathematical approach I knew had to exist.  I took a circuit logic design course many eons ago and looking up Karnaugh maps has brought back some memories. Not all of them good :)  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RO5alU6PpSU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As scalar expressions are trivial to compute, especially compraed to joins, index scans, range seeks, etc, the over-riding concern should be readability and maintainability.

One could write this is a binary search...

```
CASE WHEN a > 0 THEN
  CASE WHEN b > 0 THEN
    CASE WHEN c > 0 THEN
      CASE WHEN d > 0 THEN
        'T'
      ELSE
        'A'
      END
    ELSE
      CASE WHEN d > 0 THEN
        NULL
      ELSE
        'A'
      END
    END
  etc
etc
```

But that's not human readable, it's flight of fancy by a geek that just discovered binary trees.

One could profile the data and make the most likely scenario come first...

```
CASE WHEN a = 0                     THEN 'H'
     WHEN b = 0 AND c = 1           THEN 'H'
     WHEN c = 0                     THEN 'A'
     WHEN d = 0                     THEN 'A'
     WHEN b = 1 AND c = 1 AND d = 1 THEN 'T' END
```

But, did you notice that there's a mistake in there?  There is one, I put it there on purpose, I challenge you to find it, and even more annoyingly; correct it.

(Hint, some combinations aren't mapped and should implicitly be `NULL`.)

For those reasons, I favour the mapping table.  The code is concise, maintainability is easy *(just edit the table)*, implicit `NULL`s are taken care of, and mistakes are much harder to hide.

```
SELECT
  yourTable.*,
  yourMap.val
FROM
  yourTable
LEFT JOIN
  yourMap
    ON  yourMap.A = yourTable.A
    AND yourMap.B = yourTable.B
    AND yourMap.C = yourTable.C
    AND yourMap.D = yourTable.D
```

The map is so small, that it can be indexed and the whole index read in a single read and then live in memory.

Maybe there's a case in a high speed transactional environment to encode the logic rather than store it as data.  But in every other environment, code maintainability wins ninety nine times out of ten.

And even in the high speed transactional environment, I'd enumerate every combination, not try to collapse the code...

```
CASE
  WHEN a=0 AND b=0 AND c=0 AND d=0 THEN NULL
  WHEN a=0 AND b=0 AND c=0 AND d=1 THEN NULL
  WHEN a=0 AND b=0 AND c=1 AND d=0 THEN 'H'
  WHEN a=0 AND b=0 AND c=1 AND d=1 THEN 'H'
  etc
END
```

****K.I.S.S.****

Comment: This is exactly the example I was looking for.  I wanted to see thru another individuals eyes how they could solve this problem and of course in doing so find the best approach.  I think here that readability will take precedence and so with that I will simply enumerate each condition as opposed to trying to find the route that produces the least lines of code.

Comment: A large part of me was thinking that there was some sort of mathematical approach or in using some sort of Matrix I could solve for all explicit requested combinations and then for all other combinations they would simply output NULL or in my case 'I' for Inactive.

Comment: @shawnt00 reminded me of Karnaugh maps.  This is the mathematical approach I knew had to exist.

Comment: @CodeNovice - And if this was a critical part of the query cost, progressing to Karnaugh Maps, etc, may have merit.  As it stands, however, I would describe that as premature optimisation ; insignificant performance gains for a noticable reduction in maintainability.

Answer (score 1):

The grid is mostly "H" results so I looked closer at the two separate cases. In your instance I immediately noticed the monotonic descent from 1 to 0.

```
case
    when A * B * C * D = 1 then 'T'
    when A = 1 and A >= B and B >= C and C >= D then 'A'
    when A + B < 2 and C = 1 else 'H'
    else 'I'
end
```

or

```
case
    when A >= B and B >= C and C >= D then
        case when D = 1 then 'T' when A = 1 then 'A'
    when not (A = 1 and B = 1) and C = 1 then 'H'
    else 'I'
end
```

I don't know if I would use this approach per se. Readability is obviously a consideration. Does it facilitate your thinking to apply a "greater than" metaphor to the four input variables? Or to reduce the "H" cases to something like "must have C and never both A and B"? I would argue that these seem likely  to translate back into plain English.

This re-ordered matrix was helpful in picking out patterns.

[image: Logic table]

Comment: `ELSE 'H'` fails to deal with unmapped combinations, which should implicitly yield `NULL` *(The OP's code does.)*  Also, the OP wants to know ***why*** you recommend any particular approach.

Comment: Unmapped can just as easily be impossible input. And OP's attempt was incomplete so I wouldn't read too much into implicit nulls.

Comment: Fair point, but I wouldn't assume the difference is definitively mute, it at the very least needs to be a stated assumption.  *(You still haven't answered the Op's quesiton about **why** you'd adopt this approach.)*

Comment: Basically the mapped combinations are the explicit combinations in the request... All other combinations would fall to Null or in my actual case they are set to 'I' for Inactive.

Comment: @CodeNovice - The unmapped combinations being `'I'` or `NULL` therefore require different logic, and is an example of hidden information.